# PHP Send post data to URL and get response from that webpage

Tags: php, json, post

Is it possible to send POST data to an URL and get the response back from that webpage, it's in JSON, and use that data for something different.
If it is possible, how?

Thanks :)

EDIT: I have a form sending to another php script on another server, but i want to get the response from that script and use it in my script. The data send by the another is in JSON, but that isn't  a problem anymore.

Comment: yes it is possible, google e.g. jquery and ajax

Comment: Yes, it is possible. But it would help us better understand your problem when you can explain where exactly you're stuck as far as the code is concerned. If you're not clear on how `POST` requests work and how do we create and send `JSON` response, I suggest googling the same. You'll get a lot of helpful tutorials to get you started.

Comment: For PHP, take a look into `cURL` functions.

Comment: If you intend to send it from javascript part of your page, read up a bit on `AJAX`; If you intend to send it from the php part of your page, take a look at `cURL`.

Comment: Refer to [my article](http://qiita.com/mpyw/items/62e6e415f86eb30a5ff4) (Use translator tool)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using php curl you can achieve this as following

```
$url = "http://google.com/";

$aParameter = array('id'=>1,'name'=>'test'); //parameters to be sent

$params = json_encode($aParameter); //convert param to json string

//headers to be sent optional if no header required skip this and remove curlopt_httpheader thing from curl call
$aHeaders = array(
        'Client-Secret'=>'XXXXX',
        'Authorization'=>'xxxxxx',
        'Content-Type'=>'Content-Type:application/json',
        'accept'=>'accept:application/json'
    );


$c = curl_init();

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,  'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:11.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/11.0'); // empty user agents probably not accepted
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER,    1);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $aHeaders);

curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, $url );
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($c,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$params);
$sResponse[$key] = curl_exec($c);
```